# How to redirect nginx request to GCP bucket to get a file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I have a nginx server setup that needs to redirect the request coming from external world to GCP Bucket to get a file and serve. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What did you try? It's a URL rewrite to perform.

Comment: i haven't tried anything till now here. my basic functionality is that today we have certain files on a VM, which has nginx enabled, and whenever any request for a file comes, we serve it from the local VM Storage. Now I want to serve the files from the GCP, so if any request comes to Nginx server, we reroute the request to gcp, and serve the file